# Traverse Graph With Directed Cycles using Relationship Properties as Filters

Tags: graph, neo4j

I have a Neo4j graph with directed cycles.  I have had no issue finding all descendants of `A` assuming I don't care about loops using this Cypher query:

```
match (n:TEST{name:"A"})-[r:MOVEMENT*]->(m:TEST)
return n,m,last(r).movement_time
```

The relationships between my nodes have a timestamp property on them, `movement_time`.  I've simulated that in my test data below using numbers that I've imported as floats.  I would like to traverse the graph using the timestamp as a constraint.  Only follow relationships that have a greater movement_time than the movement_time of the relationship that brought us to this node.

Here is the CSV sample data:

```
from,to,movement_time
A,B,0
B,C,1
B,D,1
B,E,1
B,X,2
E,A,3
Z,B,5
C,X,6
X,A,7
D,A,7
```

Here is what the graph looks like:

[image: Graph]

I would like to calculate the descendants of every node in the graph and include the timestamp from the last relationship using Cypher; so I'd like my output data to look *something* like this:

```
Node:[{Descendant,Movement Time},...]
A:[{B,0},{C,1},{D,1},{E,1},{X,2}]
B:[{C,1},{D,1},{E,1},{X,2},{A,7}]
C:[{X,6},{A,7}]
D:[{A,7}]
E:[{A,3}]
X:[{A,7}]
Z:[{B,5}]
```

This **non**-Neo4J implementation looks similar to what I'm trying to do: [Cycle enumeration of a directed graph with multi edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625440/cycle-enumeration-of-a-directed-graph-with-multi-edges)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is not 100% what you want, but very close:

```
MATCH (n:TEST)-[r:MOVEMENT*]->(m:TEST)
WITH n, m, r, [x IN range(0,length(r)-2) | 
   (r[x+1]).movement_time - (r[x]).movement_time] AS deltas
WHERE ALL (x IN deltas WHERE x>0)
RETURN n, collect(m), collect(last(r).movement_time)
ORDER BY n.name
```

We basically find all the paths between any of your nodes (beware cartesian products get very expensive on non-trivial datasets). In the `WITH` we're building a collection `delta's` that holds the difference between two subsequent `movement_time` properties.

The `WHERE` applies an `ALL` predicate to filter out those having any non-positive value - aka we guarantee increasing values of `movement_time` along the path.

The `RETURN` then just assembles the results - but not as a map, instead one collection for the reachable nodes and the last value of `movement_time`.

The current issue is that we have duplicates since e.g. there are multiple paths from `B` to `A`.

As a general notice: this problem is much more elegantly and more performant solvable by using Java traversal API (http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorial-traversal.html). Here you would have a `PathExpander` that skips paths with decreasing `movement_time` early instead of collection all and filter out (as Cypher does).

Comment: Oh, this is good!  I agree, it's not 100% perfect, but I think it will do the job.  Once it comes back I'll parse the result, create pairs of name and movement_time, and then get the distinct set of them.  That will get rid of my duplicates and should be what I'm after.  I'll play around with it and let you know.

Comment: In testing this does work, and pruning duplicates was not an issue; but I agree that using Java Traversal will be much better, and performant for large graphs.  I think I'll try and get a Java implementation working.